Properties of Stochastic Processes : Stopping times
Consider the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ and the filteration $(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t\geq 0}$ i-e $$\mathcal{F}_t \subset \mathcal{F}_s \subset \mathcal{F},   \forall{t} < s $$
Assume that the decision to stop playing a game before or at time t is determined by the information $\mathcal{F}_t$ available at time t. Then this decision can be modelled by a random variable $\tau : \Omega \to [0,\infty]$ which satisfies $$ \{ \omega; \tau(\omega)\leq t\}\in \mathcal{F}_t$$ Two conditions must be satisfied to have random variable $\tau$  be the stopping time first $P(\tau =\infty)=0$ and second one $P(\tau < \infty)=1$
Let $\mathcal{F}_t$ be the information available until time t regarding the evolution of a
stock price.
Assume the price of the stock at time t = 0 is $\\\$50$ per share. Which of the following decisions are stopping times and which are not, with the appropriate reasons thereof?
(a) Sell the stock when it reaches for the first time the price of $\\\$100$ per share;
(b) Buy the stock when it reaches for the first time the price of $\\\$10$ per share;
(c) Sell the stock at the end of the year;
(d) Sell the stock either when it reaches for the first time $\\\$80$ or at the end of the year.
(e) Keep the stock either until the initial investment doubles or until the end of the year;
(f) Sell the stock when it reaches the maximum level it will ever be;
(g) Keep the stock until the initial investment at least doubles.
My answer:
Decisions given in a, b, c, d, e are stopping times. Decisions given in f and g are not stopping times.
Would you find out what would be the reasons thereof? 

Stopping time is a specific type of random time (see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stopping_time). Does first time the price reaches USD100 is contained in the information set $\mathcal{F}$? If it is, this should not be considered a random time, or a stopping time, to my knowledge. The info that you provided is therefore not enough to address the question.

Pls make sure you use the tag homework when asking a homework-type of question. Also pls show more effort: why do you reason that a, b, c, d, and e are stopping times?

It seems to me only (f) requires knowledge of the future, g can be checked based on current information ( an "if x greater than 2*y" statement in a computer program).

For all decisions given in (a), (b),(c),(d),(e),  both the conditions are met  for
$\tau$ ,a random variable  be a stopping time.
The decision in (f),requires information about future that is not contained in $\mathcal{F}_t$.Hence it is not a stopping time.
For decision given in (g),since  the initial stock price is
$ S_0= \\\$ 50 $
the general theory of stock prices state,
$ P(S_t \geq 2S_0) = P(S_t \geq \\\$ 100) < 1 $
i-e there is + ve  probability that stock never doubles its value. This contradicts the condition $P(\tau =\infty)=0$ Hence it is not a stopping time.
For decision in (e) , there are two conditions; the latter one has the occurring probability equal  to one. i-e  $P(\tau <\infty)=1$
